# What is the meaning of copies of $ \Bbb{Q}_p/ \Bbb{Z}_p$ which can occur in the Tate-Shafarevich group of elliptic curve $E$

Tags: elliptic-curves, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

I heard the number of copies of $ \Bbb{Q}_p/ \Bbb{Z}_p$ which can occur in the Tate-Shafarevich group of elliptic curve $E$ is bounded.
(cf. ''Tate-Shafarevich group for elliptic curves with complex multiplication'' by John Coates)

But I don't understand what is the meaning(definition) of

> copies of $ \Bbb{Q}_p/ \Bbb{Z}_p$ which can occur in the Tate shafarevich group of elliptic curve $E$

Tate shafarevich group is predicted to be finite, but $ \Bbb{Q}_p/ \Bbb{Z}_p$ is infinite group.So, $E(K)$ contains copies of  $ \Bbb{Q}_p/ \Bbb{Z}_p$ makes no sense.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well if the "prediction" of finiteness is not yet proven, then showing this number of copies is bounded is sort of half way towards showing that this number is zero, which, in turn, would seem to be half way towards a full proof of that "prediction".

Comment: I don't know any of the theory myself but I feel like I should mention they said "can", as in, they allowed for the possibility. That's ok, and even necessary to do, regardless of the prediction that this never happens